# Should this be a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

Should
[How to get messages in a channel in pycord and then delete them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72454515/how-to-get-messages-in-a-channel-in-pycord-and-then-delete-them)
be a duplicate?

It's linked to the following four posts.

1. [How could I grab all chat messages in a specific channel in a discord server using discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64211658/how-could-i-grab-all-chat-messages-in-a-specific-channel-in-a-discord-server-usi)
2. [How to get a list of messages for a Discord thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71453160/how-to-get-a-list-of-messages-for-a-discord-thread)
3. [How can I get a list of all the messages in a channel and then pick a random message from that list to send as a message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64142597/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-messages-in-a-channel-and-then-pick-a-random-mes)
4. [Discord.js get an array of all messages in a channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63322284/discord-js-get-an-array-of-all-messages-in-a-channel)

However, some of these posts are for a different programming language entirely, all are for a different library, and they don't talk about deleting the message object (which is what I wrote the question for in the first place).

From Stack Overflow's documentation:

> The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.

However, if none of the linked posts answer my question, is it still a duplicate?

Comment: I mean, that's kinda what you get when you ask 2 questions in one question: 1. *"get messages from a specific channel"*; 2. *"delete them"*. As for the argument about them being different libraries, tbf pycord _is_ a fork of discord.py, they're not totally dissimilar. Not to mention, you say in your question: *"As shown in the documentation, there isn't a function to delete a message from a message object"*. If that's the case, what is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6CvY.png)?, in the documentation you linked to.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine It's still part of one question, just two parts. But with the documentation, honest mistake.

Comment: So what's the issue with the duplicates? They say use [channel.history](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.TextChannel.history) which is part of pycord (as it was part of discord.py), and then you can call the delete function on each message, which you now realize exists :-). Seems like a pretty clear cut duplicate to me.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine I guess you can do the extra step, but it only answers 1/2 the question. At the very least, the link to discord.js should be removed from the post.

Comment: A question with 2 parts is 2 questions.

Comment: @philipxy Well, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/how-do-i-push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repository-and-track-it-too). Should we close it for being duplicates of two question parts?

Comment: The first question there isn't really a question, it's setup for the situation of the actual question - i.e., OP already knows how `git branch`/`git checkout -b` works. It should be edited for clarity, but there's only one *relevant* question. Many of the answers don't mention the branch creation part at all.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Does my question fall under the criteria under the answer of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423699/should-two-parted-questions-be-closed)?

Comment: What's your point? That's from a time when poorer questions were tolerated.

Comment: @philipxy How are those poorer questions?

Comment: "What's your point?"

Comment: @philipxy The community decides a lot of the moderation right? The current consensus under that question states the following: *a possible answer to the second question in most cases will answer the first one*. So, if this can be applied to my question, maybe it shouldn't be closed. Either way, I think it's fine to stay closed at this point. To be honest, being question banned has made me desperate for the past 9 months trying to change all my posts. So sorry for any trouble I caused. Have a nice day!

Comment: I still don't understand the point of your 1st comment to me. Seems maybe you are arguing that the linked post has a lot of upvotes & asks multiple questions so doesn't that make multiple questions or at least that post OK. Very clearly it is multiple independent questions & shold be closed & the upvotes are irrelevant. And the post not being closed is an artifact of lower standards when it was posted.

Comment: @philipxy If that's the case, maybe make your own post there to add to the consensus?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course we could have closed the question as

> **Needs more focus**
>
> This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Would that really have been a better experience for you?

Being closed as various duplicates gives you pointers to answers. That's clearly better, surely. If there's still something you don't understand you can now ask a new more focused question omitting all the things you now do understand.

Comment: Yea I would’ve preferred that over any of the linked posts from another programming language. Thanks!

Comment: Also I’m question banned and desperate to fix as many of my questions as I can.